# Running an @Ignored JUnit test in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, junit

In my Eclipse project (Eclipse Luna) I have a few JUnit test cases that I don't want to run in the full regression test. For instance because they require a user to be present to verify the result (such as , if a sound properly played), or because they only run properly on specific systems. These tests are mostly used manually when making changes to the class under test. I have used `@Ignore` to ignore those tests.

When I run a class with ignored tests in it from Eclipse (Run As -> Junit test) it will show the ignored tests as ignored in the test list.

**Is there a way to force run the ignored tests from Eclipse?**

Currently I always remove the `@Ignored` tag, but it is easy to forget to ignore the tests again before committing my changes. Is there a better way to do this?

I expected Eclipse to have an option in the JUnit View of an ignore test *also run Ignored tests* , but I can't find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use JUnit's [Categories](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Categories). Create a category for the tests that need manual interaction and exclude that category in your automated build.

Comment: Thanks, but here are still cases where you temporary use `@Ignore` on single test methods e.g. until some TODO is implemented or bug is fixed that needs some time. If I want to re-check if the `@Ignore` can be removed now or not, the only chance I have currently is removing and adding the `@Ignore` annotation. It would be nice to have a solution in Eclipse: either a toggle-icon to ignore `@Ignore` or a behaviour that if I explicitly run a element the `@Ignore` gets ignored - as running that currently does not make much sense as it will always be green.